# What would be a close equation representation of this repeating line pattern?

Tags: trigonometry

A quick observation might conclude that this is just a sin function, but the thing I'm looking to find the answer to is the straightness between each maximum, and brief dip before and after the maximum.

[image]

If it helps at all, following an EKG heartbeat line but less extreme maximums and minimums is the desired effect.

What would a good example trigonometric equation of this line?

Comment: Might be worth looking at [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Comment: Or $\ \mathrm{sinc}(x)\,e^{-a\,x^2}=\frac{\sin(x)\,e^{-a\,x^2}}x\ $ with $\ a\approx \frac 1{20}$.

Comment: $\cos(a\,x)\,e^{-(a\,x)^2/3}\ $ could be even better...

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't repeat.

Comment: If you want repetitions you may use something like : $\displaystyle f(x):=\cos(x)\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-6\,k\pi)^2/5}\ $ with the sum at the right a [theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). [alpha graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29*sum%28exp%28-%28x-6*k*PI%29%5E2%2F5%29%2Ck%3D-infinity..infinity%29)